# Convert Multivariate Polynomial to Matrix Representation

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, polynomials

Let's say I have a multivariate polynomial:

```
import sympy

x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 = sympy.symbols('x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4')

expressions = [
           -x_1*x_1-x_2*x_2+x_1*x_2,
           x_2*x_2-x_1*x_2,
           x_1*x_1-x_1*x_2,
           x_1*x_2,
           x_1*x_1-x_1*x_3,
           x_1*x_3,
           x_3*x_3-x_2*x_3,
           -x_2*x_2-x_4*x_4+x_2*x_4,
           x_2*x_2-x_2*x_3,
           x_2*x_3,
           -x_3*x_3-x_4*x_4+x_3*x_4,
           x_3*x_4,
          ]

model = sympy.Poly(sympy.Add(*expressions))
model

# Poly(x_1**2 - x_2*x_3 + x_2*x_4 + 2*x_3*x_4 - 2*x_4**2, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, domain='ZZ')
```

Notice that the variables are `[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4]` and so it is possible to represent the coefficients of the polynomial as a 4x4 square matrix where the coefficient of the squared terms (i.e., `x_i*x_i`) are the diagonal terms along the matrix and the off-diagonal terms depend on the coefficients of `x_i*x_j` :

```
[[1, 0,  0,  0],
 [0, 0, -1,  1],
 [0, 0,  0,  2],
 [0, 0,  0, -2]
]
```

Starting with the `sympy` polynomial, is it possible to extract the coefficients and construct the corresponding `sympy` matrix as shown above for ANY polynomial with variables `[x_1, x_2, ..., x_N]`?

At the end of the day, I'm really hoping to obtain the final matrix as a `numpy` array so that it can be used for additional computation outside of `sympy`.

Comment: Anything that you want to do can be done by processing the output of `model.as_dict()` manually. Possibly an easier approach exists if the problem is made more constrained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as all monomials are of degree 2 (e.i. `a_ij * x_i * x_j`), this should work:

```
import sympy

x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 = sympy.symbols('x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4')

expressions = [
           -x_1*x_1-x_2*x_2+x_1*x_2,
           x_2*x_2-x_1*x_2,
           x_1*x_1-x_1*x_2,
           x_1*x_2,
           x_1*x_1-x_1*x_3,
           x_1*x_3,
           x_3*x_3-x_2*x_3,
           -x_2*x_2-x_4*x_4+x_2*x_4,
           x_2*x_2-x_2*x_3,
           x_2*x_3,
           -x_3*x_3-x_4*x_4+x_3*x_4,
           x_3*x_4,
          ]

model = sympy.Add(*expressions)

Q = sympy.Rational(1, 2) * sympy.hessian(model, (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4))
sympy.pprint(Q)
```

It gives:

```
⎡1   0     0     0 ⎤
⎢                  ⎥
⎢0   0    -1/2  1/2⎥
⎢                  ⎥
⎢0  -1/2   0     1 ⎥
⎢                  ⎥
⎣0  1/2    1    -2 ⎦
```

Or, if you need an upper triangular matrix:

```
import numpy as np

h = np.array(sympy.hessian(model, (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)), dtype=float)
Q = np.triu(h) - 0.5 * np.diag(np.diag(h))
print(Q)
```

which gives:

```
[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. -1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  2.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. -2.]]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you @bb1

Comment: I have expanded this example where my expression contains over 50K terms (essentially a 225 x 225 Hessian) and the conversion from expression is consuming too much memory. Is there a more computationally efficient way to accomplish the same thing? Note that I am ultimately doing `Q = Rational(1,2) * sympy.hessian(model.as_expr(), model.gens)` followed by converting `Q` into a `numpy` matrix via `sympy.matrix2numpy(Q, dtype='float64')` so I don't know if some efficiency can be gained if I don't actually need the `sympy` representation of the Hessian matrix.